# i++ or j-- in while statement in quick sort using java

Tags: java, quicksort

I have written the partition function in quick sort like this firstly using java:

```
public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {

    int pivot = array[left];
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while(i < j) {
        while(i < j && array[j--] >= pivot); // flag1
        if(i < j) array[i++] = array[j];
        while(i < j && array[i++] <= pivot); // flag2
        if(i < j) array[j--] = array[i];
    }

    array[i] = pivot;
    return i;
}
```

Then I test the function, but found that the input array will not change when using quick sort function. I am doubtful about the code in `flag1` and `flag2`, then I change them:

```
public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right) {

    int pivot = array[left];
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while(i < j) {
        while(i < j && array[j] >= pivot)
            j--;
        if(i < j) array[i++] = array[j];
        while(i < j && array[i] <= pivot)
            i++;
        if(i < j) array[j--] = array[i];
    }

    array[i] = pivot;
    return i;
}
```

It works this time. Why does not the first code fragment work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(i < j && array[j--] >= pivot); // flag1
```

This changes j whether or not the second clause of the condition is true.

```
while(i < j && array[j] >= pivot)
  j--;
```

This only  changes j if the second clause of the condition is true.

As such, these do quite different things.

Consider the impact of the difference: you are looking for the last element of `array` for which `element < pivot`. The condition becomes false when `j` points to that element.

- If you apply method 2, `j` remains pointing to that element.
- If you apply method 1, `j` ends up pointing to the previous element;